# Angular $scope variable undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll premise this question by stating that `$scope.$apply()` doesn't work when I call it inside `addToOrder()`. My console outputs the following error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
```

As for the core issue, when I try to set the quantity of my `item` object before pushing it into my order array, it always returns *undefined*.

```
.controller('MenuItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$localstorage', 'MenuItem',   
function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $localstorage, MenuItem) {
    MenuItem.get($stateParams.menuItemId)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.menuItem = data;
    });
    $scope.addToOrder = function() {
        var item = {
            name: $scope.menuItem.name,
            id: $scope.menuItem.objectId,
            qty: $scope.quantity,
            price: $scope.menuItem.price,
            ttlPrice: ($scope.menuItem.price)
        }
        $localstorage.order.push(item);
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input col">
    <input type="number" ng-model="quantity" value="1">
</label>
<div class="item col">{{quantity}}</div><!-- verify that $scope.quantity exists -->
<button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="addToOrder()">
    Add to Cart
</button>
```

Why does `$scope.quantity` return *undefined* even though the data binding takes place and t

**ASIDE**: `$localstorage` is a module I defined as an AngularJS wrapper for accessing the native `window.localStorage` object, in case you're wondering.

**EDIT**: Here is my app.js file, where I define my states. Below are the relevant `menu` and `menu-details` states for reference...

```
.state('tabs.menu', 
  { url: '/menu', 
    views: { 
      'tab-menu': { 
        controller: 'MenuCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/menu.list.html' 
      }
    } 
})
.state('tabs.menu-details', 
  { url: '/menu-details/:menuItemId', 
    views: { 
      'tab-menu': { 
        controller: 'MenuDetailCtrl', 
        templateUrl: 'views/menu.details.html', 
        resolve: { 
          menuItemId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) { 
            return $stateParams.menuItemId; 
          }] 
        }
      } 
   } 
})
```

Comment: You only need $scope.apply if `addToOrder` is called by an event outside of the angular cycle, such as geolocation calls

Comment: if `$apply` throws an exception then it makes little sense to talk about further execution of your code.

Comment: Sorry, `$apply()` is an artifact in my controller. Please disregard. @akonsu

Comment: maybe `quantity` is created on a child scope?

Comment: I can't see where you assign $scope.quantity. There's why its undefined!

Comment: it is not visible in your code, but I assume you use ng-repeat to show multiple items. If so then you should use $parent.quantity instead.

Comment: `<input type="number" ng-model="quantity" value="1">` @Fals

Comment: @WalterBrand This state is sibling to a menu state, where I do use ng-repeat. However, this comes from a menu-details state, where only one item exists.

Comment: I think that @akonsu is right that somehow you created a child scope. $parent helps in that case. Have you tried it?

Comment: Better yet, use controllerAs to avoid this altogether

Comment: I've added a snippet from my app.js to clarify the state configuration for this page. @akonsu I tried $scope.$parent.quantity and that did not work either...

Comment: try `$parent.quantity` in the model expression

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before in the comments, you should go for the controllerAs solution. Add for each view a controllerAs property with a unique name. Then in your template you can use that name which represents the scope.

So for instance use in your view:

{
    controllerAs : 'mainctrl'
  }

and in your view {{mainctrl.quantity}}

controllerAs is invented to prevent this kinds of typical Angular headaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" ng-model="quantity" value="1">
```

For some reason, the `value` attribute does not bind to `$scope.quantity` on pageload. So, `$scope.$digest` is not listening for changes to that variable. In my `MenuItem.get()` I initialized the variable there, like so:

```
MenuItem.get($stateParams.menuItemId)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.menuItem = data;
        $scope.quantity = 1;
});
```

It works even if you keep the value attribute there. But it's trivial.

There might have been a lack of clarity on this issue because it's not farfetched to assume that `quantity` might be a preexisting property of menuItem. This was not the case. This is extra data that I attach to a local instance when generating an OrderItem. This is different from MenuItem in that a MenuItem contains the data as it would be shown on a menu. OrderItem contains data as it would be shown on an order (e.g. quantity ordered).

**ASIDE**: I [referenced this article](http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/) when researching @WalterBrand's answer. But I understand that this is meant for dealing with data between parent-child relationships, which this is not...

Thank you for you help everyone...